# ClassNotFoundException when starting E4 application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an Eclipse E4 application. When I run the application I got and ClassNotFoundException on start of the app. The gui of the app does show up and it work. How can I fix the below error when starting the application?

When I export the application to a (Windows) binary files it does compile and run without any issues. But in Eclipse it does thrown an error.

It looks like it has something to do with my Eclipse IDE plugin "Darkest Dark theme". I don't use any Darkest dark theme features in my own application. So I don't need any features of it in my own application.

```
!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.patches 4 0 2017-03-10 07:33:36.747
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager.getExtPointElements(InstrumentationManager.java:196)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager.getStartupHooks(InstrumentationManager.java:204)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager.serviceWorkspaceStarted(InstrumentationManager.java:121)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager$1.serviceChanged(InstrumentationManager.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin.getWorkspaceRoot(EcorePlugin.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.<clinit>(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getURIConverter(ResourceSetImpl.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.widget.scrollbar.FlatScrollBarsProvider cannot be found by com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar_1.7.2.201702282146
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.FlatScrollBarPlugin.start(FlatScrollBarPlugin.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.codeaffine.eclipse.ui.swt.theme.ScrollbarPreferenceApplicator.<init>(ScrollbarPreferenceApplicator.java:48)
    at com.codeaffine.eclipse.ui.swt.theme.Activator.<init>(Activator.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.RegistryCSSPropertyHandlerProvider.configure(RegistryCSSPropertyHandlerProvider.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.RegistryCSSPropertyHandlerProvider.<init>(RegistryCSSPropertyHandlerProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.CSSSWTEngineImpl.initializeCSSPropertyHandlers(CSSSWTEngineImpl.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.<init>(AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.CSSSWTEngineImpl.<init>(CSSSWTEngineImpl.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

Comment: `com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.widget.scrollbar.FlatScrollBarsProvider` is missing. Is that your code?

Comment: It's not my code and it is used in the Eclipse IDE code for the plugin 'darkest dark theme'. But I don't use it in my code and no requirements are set to use it.

Comment: It is being called from `com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.FlatScrollBarPlugin.start` which looks like you have included a plugin that requires it in your build. Go through the list of plugins in your RCP and remove it.

Comment: I checked all my plugin imports in my plugin and product and can't find any plugin related to com.codeaffine. It looks like my IDE settings overrule the imports from the plugin and product files.

Comment: Also in my run configuration there is nothing that reference to the com.codeaffine plugin

Comment: Look at the Plug-ins tab. If you have 'all workspace and enabled target plug-ins' that may be including it. You will have to change the selection to 'plug-ins selected below' and check the list that appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that `com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.widget.scrollbar.FlatScrollBarsPr‌​ovider` is missing and is being called from `com.codeaffine.eclipse.swt.FlatScrollBarPlugin.start`.

You are including an unwanted plug-in in your run.

For a Run Configuration you should look at the 'Plug-ins' tab of the configuration. Change the 'Launch From' setting from 'app workspace and enabled target plug-ins' to 'plug-ins selected below only'. This will show you a list of all available plug-ins. Deselect the ones you don't want to include in the run.

If you are not using a separate Target Platform you might want to switch using one. Using a separate Target Platform gives you better control over which plug-ins are include in your RCP.

Comment: Indeed I found some unwanted plugins in my run configuration. I already fixed it for my run configuration and I will fix it now for my debug configuration.

Comment: I will look into target platform asap. Tnx for the tip.